# Read from pipe into C string

Tags: c, memory, pipe

I want to swapn a program and capture it's output. I use `popen` to spawn it, but I just can't get the "contents" to be stored in a dynamically allocated c string (`char *`).

This is what I got:

```c
char *spawn(char *command, int *status) {
    FILE *pipe = popen(command, "r");
    
    char line[LINE_MAX];
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    
    while (fgets(line, sizeof (line), pipe)) {
        size_t line_length = strlen(line);
        
        buffer = realloc(buffer, (buffer_size + line_length) * sizeof *buffer);
        memcpy(buffer + buffer_size, line, line_length);
        buffer_size += line_length;
    }
                
    if (status) {
        *status = WEXITSTATUS(pclose(pipe));
    } else {
        pclose(pipe);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

For some weird reason the string is always slightly too long and I get random characters at the end (e.g. `���7V`). I already tried my own implementation of `strlen` which counts until a newline character appears (including it), but it didn't help. I also tried `strcpy` but this lead to a crash. I just can't find my mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Allocate one extra byte for the terminating NUL character. Then after the `while` loop add `buffer[buffer_size]  = 0;`. That is to make `buffer` a NUL terminated C string.

Comment: @kaylum Reasonable suggestion expect when `fgets()` returns `NULL` on the first iteration.  Then `buffer[buffer_size]  = 0;` leads to UB.  Starting with `char *buffer = NULL;` is useful as to return a value from the function that indicates _nothing_ read and is distinguishable from reading an initial null character.

Answer (score 1):

> some weird reason the string is always slightly too long

Code is *not* forming a *string* in `buffer` as it has no *null character* nor space for it.  Better to allocate space for the `'\0'` and copy it in.

```
// size_t buffer_size = 0;
size_t buffer_len = 0;

while (fgets(line, sizeof (line), pipe)) {
    size_t line_length = strlen(line);
    
    // buffer = realloc(buffer, (buffer_size + line_length) * sizeof *buffer);
    buffer = realloc(buffer, (buffer_len + line_length + 1) * sizeof *buffer);

    // memcpy(buffer + buffer_size, line, line_length);
    memcpy(buffer + buffer_len, line, line_length + 1);

    // buffer_size += line_length;
    buffer_len += line_length;
}
```

Robust code would also check for allocation success.